# unable to select option from select box after cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am cloning an entire div every time a `Add More Students` link is clicked.

The cloning works but unable to select an option from the cloned select box of the cloned div.

**Html**

```
      <div id="all">
        <div id="student" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Firstname</label>
                    <label style="color:red;" id="std_first_name_error"></label>
                    <div class="append-icon">
                        <input type="text" id="std_first_name" name="std_first_name1" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" minlength="4" maxlength="16" required>
                        <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Select School</label>
                    <label style="color:red;" id="std_scl_error"></label>
                    <div class="option-group">
                      <select  name="std_scl_name1" class="language" required>


                        <option value="">Select school..</option>

                        <?php foreach ($schools as $school) :?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $school->sch_id; ?>"><?php echo $school->sch_name;?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="add_student"><a><u>Add More Students</u></a></div>
```

**Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){       
        var count = 2;
        $('#add_student').click (function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var clonedEl = $('#student').first().clone();
            clonedEl.find(':text').attr('name','std_first_name'+count);
            //Add the newly div the the entire div
            $('#all').append(clonedEl);

            //$('[name="std_scl_name'+count+'"]').html($('[name="std_scl_name1"]').html());

          });
      });
        </script>
```

**Application**

[image]

Comment: Because the clone is creating Duplicate IDs. Use classes to handle events.

Comment: tnx.. tried with class, but the class is used in several instance. it clones everything. Also tried changing the name like this `clonedEl.find(':select').attr('name','std_scl_name'+count);` that also dont work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code of yours works well in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztdmgxad/). What I have changed/added is the only `<option>` elements. Still I could be able to select an element from cloned div's `<select>`.

I think what you need to check is `php` snippet and it's output. It might not feeding the `<option>` elements.

Comment: will it be the problem with same name `name="std_scl_name1" `... i tried to change the name `clonedEl.find(':select').attr('name','std_scl_name'+count);` it didnt work, do u know how to change the name dynamically.

Comment: `:select` is not valid pseudo selector. use: `clonedEl.find('select').attr('name','std_first_name'+count);`. Also one more thing, you need to increament the counter `count`

Comment: thx. It was the problem with my template. `bootstrap.min.js` was blocking the select box. i fixed it..

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute should be unique for each element. Since you use `id="student"` and `id="add_student"`, these will be cloned and result in duplicate element ids. In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8pr55pL/), those ids have been replaced with `class="student"` and `class="add_student"`.

For any further queries, remember to use the class selecter `$('.student')` and `$('.add_student')`.